Prove $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \ge \frac{1}{bc} \sqrt{a^2b^2+c^4}+\frac{1}{ac}\sqrt{b^2c^2+a^4}, a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}.$
I've tried to make the RHS $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}}$, but not sure what to do from here. Would be recommended if there was a pure AM-GM solution. I've tried Cauchy-Schwartz as well, not sure what to do from there.
